# jquery ui dialogue stacks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I stack dynamically generated ui dialogues on right corner of screen.
something like [notify](http://needim.github.io/noty/) .Notify just adds text description and I need to display something like form in window.

**Objective** is to auto stack newly generated dialogue on top of previous dialogues.

**Alternative:** I was wondering if there is an alternative to notify that can display html instead of plain text. Html render can be divs and progressbars etc

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/b5czz/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog1">
    <p>This is the default dialog </p>
</div>
<div id="dialog2" title="Basic dialog2">
    <p>This is the default dialog </p>
</div>
... more dialogues generated dynamically
```

**JAVA:**

```
$(function(){
        var dialogOpts = { position: ["right", "bottom"],stack:true, };
        $("#dialog").dialog(dialogOpts);

        $("#dialog2").dialog(dialogOpts);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on http://pinesframework.org/pnotify. This is a alternative to notify, you can use HTML, you already have simples with progressbars etc... There is a lot of alternatives, try to Google "jquery notify".